# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wundef-prefix=HAVE_,CRAS_' Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, chromebook, crouton-os

I have a chromebook for simple coding projects but am trying to open a linux desktop environment. After running the command

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/crouton /usr/local/
```

then after

```
sudo sh ~/usr/local/crouton -t unity
```

(Usually id do a different environment but this was just to test)
Ive opened a desktop environment using crouton before but after powerwashing cause i wanted to switch linux distro, ive gotten this error with EVERY attempt ive made even after repeated powerwashing.

Ran command

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/crouton /usr/local 
sudo sh /usr/local/crouton -t unity
```

to begin downloading the desktop environment but then i continue to get that error

```
Compiling CRAS (i386)...
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wundef-prefix=HAVE_,CRAS_'
```

after a couple of minutes of smooth downloading.

Comment: Looks like the script expects a newer version of gcc than you have.

Comment: So is there anything i can do? Im not very knowledgable in this kind of stuff

Comment: You probably need to upgrade your GCC.